# How to set onItemClick listener with this

Tags: android, listactivity

I am using this to retreive a list of items and place them in a list. The URL is retrieved also for each item. I am using ListActivity

```
// Get all td's that are a child of a row - each game has 4 of these
        Elements games = doc.select("tr>  td.indexList1, tr > td.indexList2");
        Elements links = doc.getElementsByTag("a"); // or getElementsByClass("b1");


        // Iterator over those elements     
        ListIterator<Element> postIt = games.listIterator();          
        while (postIt.hasNext()) {     
            // ...It 

            while (postIt.hasNext()) {     
                // Add the game text to the ArrayList     
                Element name = postIt.next();
                String nameString = name.text();
                String platform = postIt.next().text();
                Element url = name.select("a").first();

            //Here i retreive the url string for each item
                        String urlString = url.attr("href");

                String genre = postIt.next().text();
                String releaseDate = postIt.next().text();
                gameList.add(new GameRelease(nameString, platform, genre, releaseDate, urlString));
                Log.v(TAG, urlString);
            }

            this.setListAdapter(new GameReleaseAdapter(this, gameList));
        }
```

I created my own ArrayAdapter here...

```
private class GameReleaseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GameRelease> {

    private ArrayList<GameRelease> items;

    public GameReleaseAdapter(Context context,  ArrayList<GameRelease> items) {
        // TODO: make a layout for each item which you'd call (for example) itemLayout
        super(context, R.layout.item, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO: return an item view styled however you want or as shown in the tutorial
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

    }
        GameRelease o = items.get(position);
        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
        TextView plat = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.platform);
        TextView genre = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.genre);

        tt.setText(o.getName());
        bt.setText("RELEASE DATE: " +o.getReleaseDate());
        plat.setText("PLATFORM: " + o.getPlatform());
        genre.setText("GENRE: " + o.getGenre());

        return v;

}


}
```

}

How could i store the url for each item so when the item is clicked the url is sent with a extra to another activity? How can i set each item to its own url? How can i let android know that this item in the list was clicked and it should be This url for that particular item?

EDIT -  Like this? It gives me tons of syntax errors

```
            while (postIt.hasNext()) {     
                // Add the game text to the ArrayList     
                Element name = postIt.next();
                String nameString = name.text();
                String platform = postIt.next().text();
                Element url = name.select("a").first();
                String urlString = url.attr("href");

                String genre = postIt.next().text();
                String releaseDate = postIt.next().text();
                gameList.add(new GameRelease(nameString, platform, genre, releaseDate, urlString));
                Log.v(TAG, urlString);
            }

            this.setListAdapter(new GameReleaseAdapter(this, gameList));
            final GameReleaseAdapter myGameReleaseAdapter =new GameReleaseAdapter(this,gameList);

            setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    GameRelease  selectedGameRelease =myGameReleaseAdapter .getItem(position);
                    String urlString=selectedGameRelease.getUrlString();
                    //Make what you like with the url

                }
            });



        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create the `GameReleaseAdapter` in your `Activity`, make sure you have a reference to it like

in `onCreate`

1- read your `gameList`

2- after reading it, do this line:

```
final GameReleaseAdapter myGameReleaseAdapter =new GameReleaseAdapter(this,gameList);
```

3-

```
getListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                GameRelease  selectedGameRelease =myGameReleaseAdapter .getItem(position);
                String urlString=selectedGameRelease.getUrlString();
                //Make what you like with the url

            }
        });
```

`OnItemClickListener` can be found with `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

Comment: Put it where you created your `ListView` !

Comment: Inside the GameReleaseAdapter or outside in the onCreate?

Comment: try `onCreate` but make the `myGameReleaseAdapter` final, to allow inner access

Comment: Where did you get myListView from?

Comment: `I am using this to retreive a list of items and place them in a list` ,, where you will show these items ?? isnt listview ???

Comment: @MoshErsan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2508/discussion-between-coder-for-life22-and-moshersan)

Comment: I am setting the list to the adapter by this.setListAdapter(new GameReleaseAdapter(this, gameList));
There is no listview i am using.
If you look at my question code you should see that.

Comment: and where did you get items from? That is only accessible in the ArrayAdapter. not in onCreate..

Comment: `getListView.setOnItemClickListener` not `setOnItemClickListener` in step #3

Comment: Still gives a syntas at getListView and the onItemClick has syntax erorr

Comment: read this sample http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Creating-Lists-Using-The-Android-Listactivity/

Comment: Had to use this.getListView  It worked now just about to try out to see if the url is retreived right

Comment: i used a toast message to display the url and its returning null.

Comment: I got it. had to create another getter for it! =) Thanks for your help